# POP-UP to display library pictures?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, popup

Currently we have a SharePoint 2010 “Picture Library Slideshow Web Part” implemented, which is able to display pictures from a Picture Library in a Random Order. 
However, there is very little customization and when a user clicks on the picture, it opens a new tab with the picture by itself. What I would like to do instead is to open a pop-up box and display the picture with the option to see all of the pictures in the library. Something like the following but better looking, and hopefully automatically resizable.

[image]

To get the windows above to pop-up, all I had to do was:
1. Add a Content Editor
2. Click HTML and add the HTML line of code

[image]

The problem is how can we integrate both in one, and make it more user friendly.

1. Is there a webpart out there that is able to do these two things?
2. Or does it require creating a customized webpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no OOB WebPart for your requirement, but I would suggest rather than creating a webpart, you can do the entire stuff using JavaScript/jQuery + Ajax + SharePoint WebService, use SharePoint WebServices (you need Lists.asmx) to fetch data and use any third party jQuery library like jQuery UI, Kendo UI or any other library that suits your need for the pop up, you will have complete control, design the pop up window as you want

Hope this helps :)